# Python Mechanize write to TinyMCE Text Editor

Tags: python, wordpress, tinymce, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm using Python Mechanize for adding an event to WordPress but I can't seem to figure out how to write to the TinyMCE Editor in the 'Add New' Event section.

I've been able to make a draft so far by just setting the Title with some value for testing purposes but I am stuck here. What I've done so far is...

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open(url)
```

Intermediate steps to get to the correct page that don't need to be listed...

Once on the correct page I choose the form that I want to work with, select it and set the title. Once I submit I can actually travel to my drafts section in my normal chrome/firefox browser to see a draft has been created.

```
for f in br.forms():
if f.name == postForm:
    print f
    br.select_form(f.name)
    br.form['post_title'] = 'Creating from MECHANIZE'
    br.submit(name='save', label='Save Draft')
```

What would be the intermediary steps to input data into the TinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that by writing:

```
br.form['content'] = "some content"
```

You are able to write to the custom textarea. Any HTML content that you have in triple double-quotes will show up as you want once you submit the post.